# Use of undefined constant SIGTERM - > assumed 'SIGTERM'

Tags: php, window, phpunit, codeception, php-5.6

Currently running **PHPUnit** with **Codeception** on my Windows machine gives me an error:

> [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]
> Use of undefined constant SIGTERM -
> assumed 'SIGTERM'

As far as I know is that `SIGTERM` is a constant provided by [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/de/pcntl.constants.php), which is not supported in Windows. In that way this CONSTANT shouldnt be used for a test running on Windows env. at all.

#### My PHP setup:

```
PHP 5.6.17 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2016 13:28:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

#### PHPUnit

```
PHPUnit 5.7.15
```

#### Codeception

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.9
```

#### [phiremock-codeception-extension](https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension)

```
phiremock-codeception-extension v1.2.2
```

Comment: i don't use codeception much so don't know its internals but its [source code](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/search?utf8=✓&q=SIGTERM) does use this constant . Have to say that I am unaware about its internal workflows and used it on linux system only, never tried it on win.

Comment: I actually was able to reproduce the problem which is depending on phiremock-codeception-extension - https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension/issues/4 - https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension/blob/master/src/Extension/PhiremockProcess.php#L74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is depending on `phiremock-codeception-extension` which uses `SIGTERM` without checking the OS/PCNTL extension is available. So I created a Bug report at GitHub https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension/issues/4..

This are the infected code lines - https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension/blob/master/src/Extension/PhiremockProcess.php#L74

```
/**
 * Stops the process.
 */
public function stop()
{
    $this->process->signal(SIGTERM);
    $this->process->stop(3, SIGKILL);
}
```

I will update this answer once the problem has been fixed by the developer.

---

#### Update

This issue has beend fixed in [phiremock-codeception-extension v.1.2.3](https://github.com/mcustiel/phiremock-codeception-extension/tree/v1.2.3).